# What pitfalls to expect from generation of classes from database tables using Reflection.Emit and xsd files?

Tags: c#, code-generation, business-objects, reflection.emit

I am playing with class generation ( one class for a table - inheritance etc. not to be considered for now ... ). So I copied shamelessly from [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2006/02/05/137569.aspx) the Reflection.Emit code. Reworked it to be generated per table in a given database and created the files with the following batch call in the Project's bin folder : 
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir *.xsd /b') do "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe" -c -l:c# -n:BusinessObjects %i

So far so good. The idea is each time when a new db version arrives to regenerate the classes and copy them in the "real project" ( I do not need any run-time generation ) and also would like to enjoy Intellisense. What pitfalls , difficulties and problems might arrise from this type of approach, any better suggestions for those loosely described requirements  ?!

Here is the Generation code of the console app creating the assemblies :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using log4net;
    using log4net.Config;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Reflection.Emit;

    namespace GenerateAssemblies
    {

      class Program
      {

        private static readonly ILog logger =
             LogManager.GetLogger ( typeof ( Program ) );


        static void Main ( string[] args )
        {
          DOMConfigurator.Configure();  //tis configures the logger 
          logger.Debug ( "APP START" );

          DataTable dtTables = Program.GetTablesFromDb ( "POC" ) ;
          foreach (DataRow dr in dtTables.Rows)
          {
            string strTableName = dr[0].ToString () ;
            CodeEmitGeneratingAssemblies.DllGenerator.WriteXmlAndTxtFileOutOfDataTableByName (  strTableName);
            CodeEmitGeneratingAssemblies.DllGenerator.CreateAssembly ( strTableName );
          }


          Console.WriteLine ( " Should have now all the dll's " );
          Console.ReadLine ();
        } //eof method 



        static DataTable GetTablesFromDb ( string strDbName )
        {


          DataTable dt = new DataTable ( "tables" );

          string connectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=" + strDbName + ";Data Source=ysg";

          using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection ( connectionString ))
          {
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand ();

            command.CommandText = string.Format ( "SELECT name from sys.tables" );

            connection.Open ();
            dt.Load ( command.ExecuteReader ( CommandBehavior.CloseConnection ) );
          }
          return dt;
        } //eof method 


      } //eof class 


    namespace CodeEmitGeneratingAssemblies
    {
      public class DllGenerator
      {
        private static readonly ILog logger =
             LogManager.GetLogger ( typeof ( DllGenerator ) );




        public static void WriteXmlAndTxtFileOutOfDataTableByName (string strDataTableName)
        {
          DOMConfigurator.Configure ();  //tis configures the logger 
          DataTable tableData = new DataTable ( strDataTableName );

          string connectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=POC;Data Source=ysg";

          using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection ( connectionString ))
          {
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand ();

            command.CommandText = string.Format ( "SELECT * FROM [" + strDataTableName + "]");
            logger.Debug ( "command.CommandText is " + command.CommandText );
            connection.Open ();
            tableData.Load ( command.ExecuteReader ( CommandBehavior.CloseConnection ) );
          }

          tableData.WriteXml ( strDataTableName + ".xml" );
          tableData.WriteXmlSchema ( strDataTableName + ".xsd" );
        } //eof method 


        public static void CreateAssembly ( string strDataTableName )
        {
          AppDomain currentDomain = Thread.GetDomain ();

          AssemblyName myAssemblyName = new AssemblyName ( );
          myAssemblyName.Name = strDataTableName;

          AssemblyBuilder builder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly (
                              myAssemblyName,
                              AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave );

          builder.AddResourceFile ( "TableXml", strDataTableName + ".xml" );
          builder.AddResourceFile ( "TableXsd", strDataTableName + ".xsd" );

          builder.Save ( strDataTableName + ".dll" );
        }

      } //eof class 
    } //eof namespace 

    } //eof namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all the problems of using a (relational)database-driven oo design:

- not enough abstraction, no inheritance and no building of ADTs;
- classes with too many responsibilities;
- behaviour in the wrong places;
- no usable way to handle time aspects.

I prefer working the other way around. From the oo model to the database

[edit]
You could try to get a hybrid model working. Going from DB to OO for part of the app, and the other way around for another part. That allows you to slowly refactor and migrate to OO->DB.

Comment: I agree with you ... My problem is that actually the db already exists so I would have to adopt to it ..

Answer (score 0):

Duh ... oneliner with SubSonic :

```
sonic generate /override /server HOMIE /db BlogEngine /userid OMMITED /password OMMITED /out C:\code\out /generatedNamespace BlogEngine.Core.Providers.SubSonic /stripTableText be_
```